# 'float' object is not subscriptable in apply() function

Tags: python, apply

I want to create a new column "Long_Short", and fill in with strings 'Long Positions' 'Short Positions' based on column 'sum(Sensi)'

```
def LongShort(delta):
    if delta > 0:
        return 'Long Positions'
    else:
        return 'Short Positions'

df_instru["Long_Short"] = df_instru['sum(Sensi)'].apply(lambda x: LongShort(x['sum(Sensi)']))
```

I get this error:

```
'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I know I can bypass this error by applying it to the whole dataframe:

```
df_instru["Long_Short"] = df_instru.apply(lambda x: LongShort(x['sum(Sensi)']), axis=1)
```

But I don't want to do this coz it can be slow.

How can I tackle this error while only applying it to one target column?

Comment: What is the logic behind the function, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch to `numpy.where` or `np.where` for short, which can prove easier and faster for what it seems you are trying to achieve:

```
df_instru['Long_Short'] = np.where(df_instru['sum(Sensi)'] > 0, "Long positions","Short positions")
```